# Add multiple Images in ListView and get each click event

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-listview

I want to design my UI like the following Instagram's user activity screen.
With the same features (get profile picture, user Name, liked photos click event event).

How to add multiple Images in a list Item and get the click event for the added images?

[image: Instagram]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to create the ImageViews when creating your Row. Which means you will have to do this during `getView()`. When Creating a new ImageView, make it clickable using `iv.setClickable(true)` and attach a new clicklistener onto the image, which will handle the opening of the image once you clicked it. If every Image does the same, you can implement the onClickListener in the adapter and add it to every single image. This might be a smart choice if all images do the same, like opening the image you have just clicked.

within the onClick Callback you will have the view the click originated from, so you can access its id or its Tag, which will tell you what image to show.

Comment: You will have to check if the imageview actually receives the click event, the Row might catch it instead. If you cant figure it out, i might check how i solved this. Cant remember how exactly it had to be done.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using custom imageview for imagesthen make the imageview clickable by using this property...

```
<ImageView  
 android:clickable="true"  
 android:onClick="Click"  
 android:src="@drawable/img">  
 </ImageView>
```

I think this will help you...

Comment: dont do that, you will end up having a callback for each image, and if you want to be able to dynamically add images to your view, you can only add as many images as you have callbacks.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use adapter to show multiple image in list view and for click 
do something like this

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    Holder holder = null;

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = inf.inflate(R.layout.image, parent, false);
        holder = new Holder();
        holder.im1 = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        holder.im2 = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView2);

        holder.im1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                System.out.println("i is clicked");
            }
        });

        holder.im2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                System.out.println("2 is clicked");
            }
        });
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        convertView.getTag();
    }

    return convertView;
}

public class Holder {
    ImageView im1, im2;
}
```

Comment: Like this your ImageViews are limited in numbers. If you know you will never have more than 2 Images, thats okay. But if you have more? You will need to rework your layout and do some hidden/visible logic. I'd rather create them in code.